# how to join data frames with different number of rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames with different number of rows, like:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array((0, 1.0, 0.4, 0.1),
                               (1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.3),
                               (2, 0.2, 0.9, 0.2),
                               (3, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2)))
                               .toDF("id", "prop1", "prop2", "prop3")

val df2 = sc.parallelize(Array((0, 3.0, 0.2, 0.1),
                               (1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.3),
                               (2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2),
                               (3, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1),
                               (4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5)))
                               .toDF("id", "prop1", "prop2", "prop3")
```

I'd like to join the two using the id column as a key, so I do:

```
val joined = df2.join(df, df("id")===df2("id"), "leftouter")

joined.show()

+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+
| id|prop1|prop2|prop3|  id|prop1|prop2|prop3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+
|  0|  3.0|  0.2|  0.1|   0|  1.0|  0.4|  0.1|
|  1|  0.9|  0.3|  0.3|   1|  0.9|  0.3|  0.3|
|  2|  0.2|  0.5|  0.2|   2|  0.2|  0.9|  0.2|
|  3|  0.8|  0.1|  0.1|   3|  0.9|  0.2|  0.2|
|  4|  0.3|  0.5|  0.5|null| null| null| null|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

at this point two questions:

- why the second id column is added? how can I get rid of it?
- how to put null values to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the second "id" column, first rename it:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array((0, 1.0, 0.4, 0.1),
                               (1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.3),
                               (2, 0.2, 0.9, 0.2),
                               (3, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2)))
                               .toDF("id2", "prop1", "prop2", "prop3")
```

I also renamed the names of the other columns to avoid ambiguity (and an `AnalysisException`).

```
val df2 = sc.parallelize(Array((0, 3.0, 0.2, 0.1),
                               (1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.3),
                               (2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2),
                               (3, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1),
                               (4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5)))
                               .toDF("id", "prop1_2", "prop2_2", "prop3_2")
```

Now, `drop` the unwanted `id2` column

```
val joined = df2.join(df, df("id2")===df2("id"), "outer").drop("id2")
```

To provide a default value in case of nulls, use `na` and `fill`:

```
joined.na.fill(0).show

+---+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
| id|prop1_2|prop2_2|prop3_2|prop1|prop2|prop3|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|  0|    3.0|    0.2|    0.1|  1.0|  0.4|  0.1|
|  1|    0.9|    0.3|    0.3|  0.9|  0.3|  0.3|
|  2|    0.2|    0.5|    0.2|  0.2|  0.9|  0.2|
|  3|    0.8|    0.1|    0.1|  0.9|  0.2|  0.2|
|  4|    0.3|    0.5|    0.5|  0.0|  0.0|  0.0|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
```

There are a couple of ways to call `fill`, you can read up on it in the [API documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions). In the example I provided, `fill(0)` replaces null values in numeric columns with the value `0`.

Comment: If you can't rename it at the source, you can use the `withColumnRenamed` method of `DataFrame` like so: `val dfRenamed = df.withColumnRenamed("id", "id2")`. As for the dataframes not having the same number of rows, you can specify the join type depending on what you need. In my answer I specified "outer", so that the join becomes a left outer join.

Comment: yeah I have deleted my comment because I realized withColumnRenamed() was an option... just accepted your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the Torres Answer you can select only what you require to show. Something like this: -

```
joined.select(df2("id"), df("prop1"),df("prop2"),df("prop3")).na.fill(0).show()
```